# __ldg causes slower execution time in certain situation

Tags: linux, cuda, nvcc

I posted this issue already yesterday, but wasnt well received, though I have solid repro now, please bear with me. Here are system specs:

- Tesla K20m with 331.67 driver,
- CUDA 6.0,
- Linux machine.

Now I have a global memory read heavy application therefore I tried to optimize it using `__ldg` instruction on every single place where I am reading global memory. However, `__ldg` did not improve performance at all, running time decreased roughly 4x. So my question is, how comes that replacing `glob_mem[index]` with `__ldg(glob_mem + index)` can possibly result into decreased performance? Here is a primitive version of my problem for you to reproduce:

**MAKE**

```
CPP=g++
CPPFLAGS=-Wall -O4 -std=c++0x -lcudart -lcurand
LIBDIRS=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
NVCC=nvcc
NVCCINCLUDE=/usr/local/cuda/include
NVCC_COMPILER_FLAGS=-Iinclude/ -O4 -arch compute_35 -code sm_35 -c
TARGET=example

.PHONY: all clear clean purge

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): kernel.o main.cpp
    @echo Linking executable "$(TARGET)" ...
    @$(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) $(addprefix -I,$(NVCCINCLUDE)) $(addprefix -L,$(LIBDIRS)) -o $@ $^

kernel.o: kernel.cu
    @echo Compiling "$@" ...
    $(NVCC) $(addprefix -I,$(NVCCINCLUDE)) $(NVCC_COMPILER_FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean: clear

clear:
    @echo Removing object files ...
    -@rm -f *.o

purge: clear
    @echo Removing executable ...
    -@rm -f $(TARGET)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>

#include "kernel.cuh"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    double result = GetResult();
    auto elapsed = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;

    printf("%.3f, elapsed time: %.3f \n", result, (double)chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count());
    return 0;
}
```

**kernel.cuh**

```
#ifndef kernel_cuh
#define kernel_cuh

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

double GetResult();

#endif
```

**kernel.cu**

```
#include "kernel.cuh"

class DeviceClass
{
    double* d_a;
public:
    __device__ DeviceClass(double* a)
        : d_a(a) {}

    __device__ void foo(double* b, const int count)
    {
        int tid = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x);
        double result = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            result += d_a[i];
            //result += __ldg(d_a + i);
        }

        b[tid] = result;
    }
};

__global__ void naive_kernel(double* c, const int count, DeviceClass** deviceClass)
{
    (*deviceClass)->foo(c, count);
}

__global__ void create_device_class(double* a, DeviceClass** deviceClass)
{
    (*deviceClass) = new DeviceClass(a);
}

double GetResult()
{
    const int aSize = 8388608;
    const int gridSize = 8;
    const int blockSize = 1024;

    double* h_a = new double[aSize];
    for (int i = 0; i <aSize; ++i)
    {
        h_a[i] = aSize - i;
    }

    double* d_a;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, aSize * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, aSize * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    double* d_b;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, gridSize * blockSize * sizeof(double));

    DeviceClass** d_devicesClasses;
    cudaMalloc(&d_devicesClasses, sizeof(DeviceClass**));
    create_device_class<<<1,1>>>(d_a, d_devicesClasses);

    naive_kernel<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_b, aSize, d_devicesClasses);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    double h_b;
    cudaMemcpy(&h_b, d_b, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_a);
    cudaFree(d_b);
    return h_b;
}
```

So what is it all about... In my application I have some global data pointed to by member variable of class DeviceClass which is created on device, exactly as new/delete CUDA demo shows.

- Build this using make and then execute ./example,
- Running this example as is yields: "35184376283136.000, elapsed time: 2054676.000".
- After I uncomment line 17 in kernel.cu and comment out line right above it the result becomes: "35184376283136.000, elapsed time: 3288975.000"
- so using __ldg decreases performance quite significantly even though I was using it up until now without any issues on different occasions. What could be the cause?

Comment: There is a difference in loop unrolling, in your `foo` function, for reasons that are not entirely clear to me yet.  To eliminate this effect on the results, add `#pragma unroll 8` before the for-loop in that function, and re-run your test(s).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `__ldg` is just a more convinient way to use texture cache, which is tuned for semi-random access. Your particular kernel has purely linear reads, which are already fast thanks to coalescing. Additional caching is not helpful here, and might increase latency. Besides, examining PTX for two cases reveals that compiler generates quite different code for the main loop.

Comment: FYI, my initial solution was to have member variable d_a of DeviceClass as staticaly sized array. Also I had __host__ constructor, using which I created the object on host and then used cudaMemcpy to create its copy on device which worked nicely with staticaly sized arrays. Using that approach yielded great results, but obviously I dont want to use staticaly sized arrays because size depends on external configuration file which drives my computation.

Comment: @Robert Crovella - I have achieved execution time of 1574479.000 using your approach, though this fix is not entirely clear to me. I guess nvcc should take care of such stuff, so is it some bug in compiler or.. ?

Comment: I believe the compiler is unable to determine the expected trip count for the loop, and so it's being quite conservative to avoid surprises if you pass `count` = 3, for example, although I can't quite explain the difference in unrolling strategy between the two cases.  Nevertheless, when I instruct unrolling of a level greater than 3 (I have tried 4, 8, and 64), I see expected results, that is that the `__ldg` code is faster.

Comment: Unfortunately in my original application the computation is a fair bit more complex, containing nested for loops reading from four global arrays etc. I tried shuffle around with various unrolling counts but did not achieve expected speedup. I also tried adding a local variable poiting to d_a within foo method, so each thread has its own pointer and while this helped performance, it was still worse than original pointer[index] access of global memory. I just thought it might be worthh mentioning here.

Comment: The L1 cache, shared memory, or constant memory are all better fits for this workload, since all threads are concurrently accessing the same element of d_a[i].  To use the L1 cache, block your inner loop to maximize reuse.  Shared memory and constant memory would require more refactoring along the lines of an N-body implementation. https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/tree/master/nbody

Comment: As I stated in description already - this is just very primitive, rather stupid example to demonstrate the problem I encountered. The question is "why does the performance decrease after using __ldg?" and not "how should I optimize my primitive example?". Also, your advice to use shared memory is OK, but not in the situation where I have to access hundreds of megabytes of data as is in my case - shared memory size is rather limiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the version using `__ldg` being slower is the fact that the NVCC compiler is not able to perform loop unrolling optimizations correctly in this particular scenario. The issue was submitted to NVIDIA with ID 1605303. The most recent response from NVIDIA team is as follows:

> Although, we have not communicated this to you, we have done prior investigations into your issue. The solution to your issue is improving our loop-unrolling heuristic in the back-end compiler – the compiler embedded inside of ptxas. We evaluated the possibility of resolving this issue in CUDA 8.0, but an initial solution that fixed your problem caused unacceptable regressions. Because of other constraints, we were not able to develop a proper solution in time for it to be done for CUDA 8.0.
>
> We are actively working to resolve your issue in the future CUDA release(that following of CUDA 8.0). We will ensure that we keep you informed of our progress moving forward.

Comment: Fixed in CUDA 9?

Comment: No idea, haven't worked with CUDA since I finished my thesis, feel free to try it out tho :)