# CUDA __device__ function as class member: Inlining and performance?

Tags: c++, cuda

I plan to partition my computation into a fine-grained framework of functions/classes which encapsulate a certain part.

Something like this, but with **even more classes and typically longer parameter lists**:

```
class Point{

  Coordinates thisPoint;
  Value getPointValue();
  Point getPoint(Offset offset); 
  Point getNumNeighbors();
  Point getNeighbor(int i);
  // many more

}

class Operator{

  void doOperation(Point p){
    // calls some of the functions in Point
  }

}
```

Clearly, this would be a good practice in any object oriented language. But it's intended to run on a CUDA GPU. What I don't know: When I qualify all these fine-grained functions as `__device__` and call them in a kernel - how will they be implemented? Will I have a significant overhead for the calls of the member functions or will this be inlined or otherwise efficiently optimized? Normally, these functions are extremely short but called many, many times.

Comment: I followed the object oriented pattern in all my CUDA applications and never experienced significant performance overhead but don't have charts or so to back up my statement. I guess develop your app and then profile it, comparing against version where `__device__` functions are not member functions... Actually, I did experience a performance issue which was slightly related, see more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25024526/3242721) but that was caused by optimizer not being able to unwrap loops properly in very specific situation which included call to `__device__` member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPU compiler will aggressively [inline](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline) functions for performance reasonse.  In that case, there should be no particular impact to performance.

If a function cannot be inlined, then the usual performance overhead would occur, involving the creation of a stack frame and a call to a function -just as you would observe on a CPU call to a non-inlined function.

If you have concerns about a specific example, you can create a short test code and look at the generated assembly language (SASS) by using `cuobjdump -sass myexe` and determine whether or not the function was inlined.

There are no [general restrictions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#restrictions) on inlining of `__device__` functions that are class members/methods.

Comment: So I won't run into problems when using a `this` pointer inside an inlined function? At a first glance, it should not be a problem, but C++ something exhibits a behavior that an inexperienced person would not expect.

Comment: I'm not aware of any CUDA limitations in C++ around the usage of `this`.  If you have a question about it, why not ask a new question?  Better yet, try it.  If you run into difficulty, ask about the difficulty you are having.