# CUDA: huge performance impact calling member functions

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, member

When I understand this `Robert Crovella's` SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26715787/3179492) correctly the GPU compiler should aggressively inline functions *for performance reasons*.

I have here a test case where it does not happen and even this very simple function is not inlined and the compiler generates each time a call to the member function:

```
__device__ auto foo::isMemberHighest( int iParameterBar ) -> bool
{
    return iParameterBar == 1;
}
```

Running the `-cubin` parameter and disassembling it with `nvdiasm` I get this output:

```
//--------------------- .text._ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi --------------------------
    .section    .text._ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi,"ax",@progbits
    .sectioninfo    @"SHI_REGISTERS=7"
    .align  64
        .global         _ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi
        .type           _ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi,@function
        .size           _ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi,(.L_969 - _ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi)
_ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi:
.text._ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi:
        /*0000*/                   MOV R0, R6;
        /*0008*/                   MOV R5, R5;
        /*0010*/                   MOV R4, R4;
        /*0018*/                   MOV R4, R4;
        /*0020*/                   MOV R5, R5;
        /*0028*/                   MOV R4, R4;
        /*0030*/                   MOV R5, R5;
        /*0038*/                   MOV R0, R0;
        /*0040*/                   MOV R0, R0;
.L_605:
        /*0048*/                   ISUB R3.CC, R4, RZ;
        /*0050*/                   ISETP.NE.X.AND P0, PT, R5, RZ, PT;
        /*0058*/                   PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, !P0, PT, PT;
        /*0060*/                   PSETP.AND.AND P0, PT, !P0, PT, PT;
        /*0068*/                   NOP;
        /*0070*/                   SSY `(.L_449);
        /*0078*/               @P0 BRA `(.L_450);
        /*0080*/                   BRA `(.L_450);
.L_450:
        /*0090*/                   NOP.S              (*"TARGET= .L_449 "*);
.L_449:
        /*0098*/                   ISETP.EQ.AND P0, PT, R0, 0x1, PT;
        /*00a0*/                   SEL R0, RZ, 0x1, !P0;
        /*00a8*/                   MOV R0, R0;
        /*00b0*/                   MOV R4, R0;
        /*00b8*/                   RET;
.L_606:
        /*00c0*/                   EXIT;
.L_604:
        /*00c8*/                   EXIT;
.L_451:
        /*00d0*/                   BRA `(.L_451);
.L_969:
```

Between `/*0098*/` and `/*00a0*/` there is the compare command and then the `return`.

My C++ code has 5 member calls to this function and I see in the disassembled code exactly 5 calls to this function:

```
JCAL `(_ZN27foo15isMemberHighestEi);
```

I have now this problem: In the beginning - when I had a pure C code - I had a one big function which had a very good performance [I "inlined" the code with a `#define`]. Then I adapted it - encouraged - by the comments and documentation to C++ with classes and now my code is by factor 1'500! slower.

Before 18m iterations needed around 73ms - now 560k iterations need 3'300ms! This means it is slower by factor 1'500 which is naturally very frustrating. Of course this is not the only one member function which causes this delay. I have around 10 of them which leads to 50 `call` statements [including the function overhead] per iteration and apparently here is the bottleneck.

What can I improve or is the only solution to "dismantle" the code back to the awful C code?

The code does not change when I put the member code into the class declaration. This means, the compiler "knows" already the code of the member function. AND, the code does not change at all if I change the optimization level `-O1 -O2 -O3`!

**UPDATE:**

Compiled with this statement:

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin/nvcc -cubin -O3 -Xcompiler -Wall -Xcompiler -Wextra
   -Xcompiler -Werror -std=c++11 --compile --relocatable-device-code=false
   -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30  -x cu -o CudaCore.cubin "../cuda/CudaCore.cu"
&& nvdisasm CudaCore.cubin > CudaCore.cubin.asm
```

Comment: do you have the code in multiple files?  Are you using separate compilation and linking/relocatable device code?

Comment: @RobertCrovella The class declaration is in a `.h` file which is then included in the `.cu` file but the whole class definition is in **one** file. It is compiled in one step and for this test case I did not link it. I only called `nvcc` with the parameters and ran the  disassembler. Linker is therefore not involved for this version of code.

Comment: I regret but that's simply impossible. You are doing something wrong (and looking at the disassembly this looks *very much* like debug mode). Please post a [MCVE] that does exhibit that behavior and I'm willing to eat my keyboard. By the way the `inline` keyword in this context does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum Now is in Europe 2am. I will create the MCVE tomorrow. inline-command: Yes, I know; this "remained" from testing around and I removed it now. Just to consider: The disassembled code shows that code generated by CUDA **AND I could NOT believe it neither**. I ran lot of different tests/constellations before I posted this issue. Would it help when I post the whole disassembled file via a file hoster?

Comment: The disassembly screams "this was compiled in debug mode", so no, that wouldn't help. What would help is you cleaning *all* binaries, double checking your command line, and trying a fresh build. And then posting an MCVE.

Comment: @HubertApplebaum You are the best! Please post the answer and I will accept it. Indeed I idiot "forgot" I enabled once the debug mode because I had a crash and I needed the symbolic information. I apologize this mistake! I checked now the generated code and it is as Robert wrote already "years" ago: The CUDA compiler inlines the whole code - unbelievable when I saw it. I am so sorry!

Comment: Good to know I won't be eating my keyboard today! (I wasn't too worried though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into somewhat of an answer:

I have yet to see a case where C++ is slower than C.
Your code is slower simply because it was **obviously** compiled in debug mode.

And I can't stress that *obviously* enough.

Comment: I used the option `-G` which generates device debug information. I have to admit that I understood it that way there are "added only" symbols, especially due to the fact the optimization was still available and `nvcc` did not complain `- O3` was set together with the `-G` option. For me this discrepancy could be better "handled" by `nvcc`.